# Trying to get Count('foo__bar') inside annotate()

Tags: django, django-models

Im trying to get the following line works:

```
artists = models.Artists.objects.all().annotate(tot_votes=Count('votes__work')).order_by('-tot_votes')
```

(i.e. I want simply to annotate the count of all votes corresponding to every artist.)

But whenever the above line is executed I get the `FieldError` error `Cannot resolve keyword 'votes' into field`.

Where

```
class Votes(models.Model):
    work = models.OneToOneField(Works, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='work')
    user = models.OneToOneField(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='user')
```

and

```
class Works(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artists, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='artist')
    # other irrelevant fields
```

OR simply the relation between the tables is (Votes --> Works --> Artists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got that relationship the wrong way round, haven't you? Artist doesn't have any kind of direct relationship to Votes, it only does to Works. The annotate call should be to `Count('work__votes')`.

(Also note that normal naming convention for Django is to use singular names: Vote, Work, Artist.)